# Installshield 2013 Merge Module + WIX C# Custom Action Project

Tags: c#, dll, wix, installshield

My End Goal: write a merge module in Installshield 2013 that can find a xml file on disk and modify it.  Finding the file requires using a 3rd party interop to query for the location of the file.  This is because the file is installed by another product.

I've tried a few things:

- Using the Sample Managed Class Library DLL's provided with Installshield.  This works well until the 3rd party classes are used in the code.
- Using the WIX C# Custom Action Project :  As far as I can see, there is no option to add the standard DLL to a merge module only a MSI in Installshield.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Questions:

- What is the best way to achieve this functionality using Installshield?
- Can I install my C# dll as well as the needed Interop before calling the custom action in my DLL?  Would that be a good approach?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third party assemblies can be included in an InstallShield Managed Code Custom Action, but it involves editing the IsClrWrap table to [list the dependencies](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=7220&d=...) (the link points to a doc file).

If you instead use a WiX DTF action, it generates what InstallShield calls an MSI DLL, as the entry points are callable directly by MSI. You don't have to use the "Standard DLL" wrapper functionality.